# How to use Tamil typewriter keyboard in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I have enabled the tamil keyboard in Ubuntu 14.04:

[image]

I activated all the Tamil keyboards:

[image]

none of the keyboards support real Tamil Typewriter layout.
like, in typewriter first we have to type **்** then **ம** so that we will get **ம்**
but all the keyboard layout works in reverse, first we have to type **ம** then **்** then only we get **ம்**
is there anyway to use the Real Typewriter method?

**EDIT**
I installed ibus-m17n and got more tamil keyboard entries, but none of them works as original typewriter. 
All other keyboard entries: 
[image]

Any other package should I try?

Answer (score 0):

Install the *ibus-m17n* package and relogin. Then you will find a few additional Tamil input sources in Text Entry. Hopefully one of those, e.g. "Tamil (typewriter (m17n))", is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @gunnar, I tried, but again, none of the keyboard works what I expected.

Comment: @M.Kumaran: Sorry to hear that. Hopefully someone else can provide more useful guidance.